# Simplified way to search/compare text

Tags: c#

I am used to doing it like this:

```
if (string1.ToLower()==string2.ToLower) ...
```

But are there other, more simplified, ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String.Compare method, it is much more elegant.
This is article about method and really nice example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc190529(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to check for "Equality" with case in-senstive comparison then use [`String.Equals` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a parameter to specify case in-sensitive comparison. Like:

```
if (String.Equals("test 1", "Test 1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Or

```
if (String.Equals("test 1", "Test 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

`String.Compare` would be useful if you are trying to compare strings for ordering.

Before converting to a upper/lower case see: [The Turkish İ Problem and Why You Should Care](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Equals` function

```
if (string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using string.Compare

```
string.Compare("test 1", "Test 1", true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the string.Compare() method overload that allows you to ignore case such as:

```
string.Compare(string1, string2, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

String.Compare nocase will solve your issue.

```
string s1 = "Animal";
string s2 = "animal";
string.Compare(s1,s2,true)
```

will return zero
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx